# Error executing stored procedure in sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_DELETE_CUSTOMER
(

   TRN   IN    NUMBER

)
AS

BEGIN

     if to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi')  BETWEEN '09:00' and '10:00' AND to_char(sysdate, 'dy'
) in ('mon', 'fri') then 

          DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE TRN_NUMBER =TRN;         
     ELSE  
           dbms_output.put_line ('Process is outside of normally working hours');    
    END IF; 
END;
/
BEGIN

Execute SP_DELETE_CUSTOMER(1223345);

END;
/
```

Comment: So are you going to tell us what the error was, or are we just supposed to guess?

Answer (score 1):

`EXECUTE` implies an anonymous block. You need either:

```
BEGIN
    SP_DELETE_CUSTOMER(1223345);
END;
/
```

Or just:

```
Execute SP_DELETE_CUSTOMER(1223345);
```

Comment: WHEN I TRY "Execute SP_DELETE_CUSTOMER(1223345);" I STILL GET AN ERROR, SAYING INVALID SQL STATEMENT  .....WHEN I USE THE "BEGIN
    SP_DELETE_CUSTOMER(1223345);
END;
/" IT EXECUTE BUT NOTHING IS DONE ON THE TABLE

Comment: Well, you asked this question on a Wednesday, when the second part of your WHERE clause will always be false, so I wouldn't expect it to delete any records. As for the output, I forget if you need to `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` in Sql Developer or not.